# How can I return rows that have the latest date?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query returns data such as:

```
ID |    ProcessID   | Type| Value | Date
--------------------------------------------------
1  |        2       | A   |  10   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
1  |        2       | B   |  20   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
1  |        2       | C   |  30   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
1  |        1       | A   |  11   | 1/6/2016 12:48:04 PM
1  |        1       | B   |  21   | 1/6/2016 12:48:04 PM
1  |        1       | C   |  31   | 1/6/2016 12:48:04 PM
2  |        4       | A   |  10   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
2  |        4       | B   |  20   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
2  |        4       | C   |  30   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
2  |        3       | A   |  11   | 6/21/2016 09:41:07 AM
2  |        3       | B   |  21   | 6/21/2016 09:41:07 AM
2  |        3       | C   |  31   | 6/21/2016 09:41:07 AM
```

However, I really only care to get the most recent data for Type's A, B, and C. Such that my return would look like this:

```
ID |    ProcessID   | Type| Value | Date
--------------------------------------------------
1  |        2       | A   |  10   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
1  |        2       | B   |  20   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
1  |        2       | C   |  30   | 2/23/2016 10:10:42 AM
2  |        4       | A   |  10   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
2  |        4       | B   |  20   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
2  |        4       | C   |  30   | 7/21/2016 11:28:22 AM
```

I've tried using max in the select clause but that is not working.

Here is my sql, limited for the sake of example to one "ID", along with a sample of the actual return:

```
select f.folderrsn,fpi.processrsn,fpi.infocode, fpi.infovalue, fp.enddate
from folderprocessinfo fpi
join folderprocess fp on fp.processrsn = fpi.processrsn
join folder f on f.folderrsn = fp.folderrsn
where fpi.infocode in (51437,51438,51439)
and trunc(f.issuedate) > '01-JAN-16'  
and not fpi.infovalue is null
and f.folderrsn = 11179547 --limited to one "ID" for example
order by fp.enddate asc
```

Return:

```
"FOLDERRSN","PROCESSRSN","INFOCODE","INFOVALUE","ENDDATE"
"11179547","37159700","51437","91","6/2/2015 10:27:46 AM"
"11179547","37159700","51438","0","6/2/2015 10:27:46 AM"
"11179547","37159700","51439","145.5","6/2/2015 10:27:46 AM"
"11179547","37540455","51437","91","7/24/2015 6:44:08 AM"
"11179547","37540455","51438","0","7/24/2015 6:44:08 AM"
"11179547","37540455","51439","145.5","7/24/2015 6:44:08 AM"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with f as (
      select f.folderrsn, fpi.processrsn, fpi.infocode,
             fpi.infovalue, fp.enddate
      from folderprocessinfo fpi join
           folderprocess fp
           on fp.processrsn = fpi.processrsn join
           folder f
           on f.folderrsn = fp.folderrsn
      where fpi.infocode in (51437, 51438, 51439) and
            trunc(f.issuedate) > '01-JAN-16' and
            fpi.infovalue is not null
     )
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by processid, type order by enddate desc) as seqnum
      from f
     ) f
where seqnum = 1
order by enddate asc;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. I'm new to SQL, and I am looking for ways to improve. You seem experienced. Would you recommend formatting my queries as you have done in the first set of parenthesis for readability?

Comment: This is not quite the solution. I should get exactly three rows of data for each processrsn (processid), one for each infocode (type).  I can get the data I'm after by querying for one infocode at a time, but for the sake of exercise, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Chris: consider editing your question to make your requirement clearer. What you just commented about the `processid` is not clearly stated or illustrated anywhere in your question.

Comment: @sstan-  It is illustrated in the example of what my desired return should look like.

Comment: @ChrisD. . . . You need to change the `partition by` clause (as I just did).  As for my indenting style, I highly recommend it.  I explain more why I choose this style in the first chapter of **Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel, Second Edition**.

Comment: @Gordron - Thank you. This is a great solution, and you have opened my eyes to a slew of functions that I had no idea even existed. In your book, do you touch on WITH, OVER, PARTITION BY, and ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: @ChrisD. . . . Yes, I do.  They are very important functions for analysis.

Comment: @Gordon - I need a copy. I'm very very lucky to have gotten the help of a true expert!